# HTML time tag for duration

Tags: html, time, semantics, semantic-markup

I need to display the duration of a video. Should I use `<time>` or should it be used only for displaying time as in a clock?

**Example**

Is this correct HTML5?

```
<p>Duration: <time>3:30 min</time>.</p>
```

Or should `<time>` be used only on a situation like this?

```
<p>Good morning. The actual time is: <time>9:45</time></p>.
```

**Docs**

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) presents the following definition:

> The HTML  element represents either a time on a 24-hour clock or a precise date in the Gregorian calendar (with optional time and timezone information).
>   This element is intended to be used presenting dates and times in a machine readable format. This can be helpful for user agents to offer any event scheduling for user's calendar.

However, the definition in [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/time.html) is somewhat different, and it refers duration:

> Specifies the date or time that the element represents.
>
> **Value:** Any one of the following:
>
> - (...)
> - a valid duration string as defined in the [HTML5] specification
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> PT4H18M3S
>
> 4h 18m 3s
> ```

So, I'm not sure if I should be using `<time>` in this situation or not. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) for durations.

But the value has to be a [valid duration string](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#valid-duration-string), which "3:30 min" is not.

You can use the [`datetime` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#attr-time-datetime) to specify the correct value, and keep "3:30 min" as element content, e.g.:

```html
<time datetime="3m 30s">3:30 min</time>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the spec allows the `time` element to have a duration as a value, it means it can be used this way. The only [limitation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-duration-string) I found in the spec is that you can't specify months or years for a duration — only weeks, days, hours, minutes, and seconds. But it shouldn't be a problem for a duration of the video).

Comment: How do you make `<time>` work? I'd like to use it that way, it would look very semantic.

Comment: @zer00ne see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element:valid-duration-string