# HTML <time> time interval

Tags: html, seo

With the `time` element you can add a machine readable date time:

> The HTML `<time>` element represents either a time on a 24-hour clock or
>   a precise date in the Gregorian calendar (with optional time and
>   timezone information). [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time)]

Is there a way to describe a machine readable time interval e.g. the business of a shop? So we have something like this

```
<time datetime ="???">09:00 - 12:00</time>
```

and if yes does this make sense for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can mark up time durations using the `time` element, for example:

```
<time datetime="PT23H 9M">23 hours, 9 minutes</time>
```

Is it useful for SEO? No, at least not yet, but I would recommend using this markup if you can so you are future ready!

For more information see [best of time](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time/).

Comment: Cool thing with the durations. But does this match a situation like this We are opened <time datetime="?">09:00 - 12:00</time>, too?

Comment: Yes, <time datetime="PT10H">09:00 - 19:00</time> is also ok. Nesting time elements is also allowed, so: <time datetime="PT10H"><time datetime="09:00">09:00</time> - <time datetime="19:00">19:00</time></time> is also valid.

Comment: @crashbus, I didn't think that you had, I was asking whoever did downvote is all, apologies that it sounded like I was questioning you.

Answer (score 4):

While you can (and should) use the [`time` element for durations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31591343/1591669), it doesn’t convey what this duration is for.

If you want to convey that these are the opening hours of a shop, you might want to include structured data. For example, by using the syntax RDFa together with the vocabulary Schema.org (which is supported by several search engines).

Schema.org provides the [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification) property, which takes an [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification) as value.

In RDFa (Lite), this could look like:

```
<body typeof="schema:LocalBusiness">

  <div property="schema:openingHoursSpecification" typeof="schema:OpeningHoursSpecification">

    <time datetime="3h">
      <time property="schema:opens">09:00</time> - <time property="schema:closes">12:00</time>
    </time>

  </div>

</body>
```