# What HTML tag is semantically suitable for an "alternating" list with "intervals"?

Tags: html, html-lists, markup, semantic-markup

Let's assume I want to present a TODO list such as this:

```
8:00
    Walk the dog!
8:30
    Clean the car!
9:20
    Rob the bank!
9:21
    Run the dog!
22:00
    Have a beer!
22:05
```

My first though was to use a *definition list*, but it's not a great fit:

```
<dl>
    <dt>8:00</dt>
    <dd>Walk the dog!</dd>
    <dt>8:30</dt>
    <dd>Clean the car!</dd>
    <dt>9:20</dt>
    <dd>Rob the bank!</dd>
    <dt>9:21</dt>
    <dd>Run the dog!</dd>
    <dt>22:00</dt>
    <dd>Have a beer!</dd>
    <dt>22:05</dt>
    <!--<dd>Missing element???</dd>-->
</dl>
```

AFAIK, a `<dt>` must be followed by one or more `<dd>` tags. But the last time (22:05) does not have any (non-empty-)element to follow it.

Furthermore, the points in time given semantically should correspond just as much to the element before it as the one after it, but that relationship is lost here too.

Is there any other combination of HTML tag(s) that might fit this data better?

Comment: A good old table might do here as well - after all, you have two _columns_, one with times when stuff starts, and the second one with the stuff. If nothing happens any more after the last time point, the corresponding stuff cell can be left empty. (Accessibility-wise you might also place a text there for screen-reader users, such as “nothing more” or “day’s activities end here” - and hide it for seeing users.)

Comment: @CBroe I guess so, but the thing is that I don't want times and tasks to be on the same row (neither semantically, nor visually) -- the interleaving aspect is important to me. For that, I *still* could use a table but then I would have to leave half of all its cells empty, which seems a bit crufty...

Comment: But they _do_ belong together semantically – or how do they not?

Comment: @CBroe Times are only points in time. Tasks in my example above take place in the intervals between them. Their duration is determined by both the time preceding it (the start time) and following it (the end time). Neither is more important than the other. Placing the start time on the same row but the end time on the row of the next task creates an annoying asymmetry IMO, both semantically and visually.

Comment: I think it is fairly common practice to have the start time of the next task/item/show mean the end for the current one – that logic is used in timetables all over the world, and people know what it means. Trying to deviate from the clear structure this makes for at all cost on the semantic level is likely not such a good idea. If you want it to _look_ differently, that’s a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML can’t convey this. You have to make the durations/intervals explicit (i.e., with natural language).

While [the `time` element can be used for durations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31591343/1591669), the duration has not a specific date as start/end. So you can convey that walking the dog takes 30 minutes, but not that you walk the dog from 8:00 to 8:30. By nesting `time` elements, you can (at most) hint at that.

The equivalent for non-time-related values is the [`data` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-data-element), but there are no standardized formats, so you can’t convey that a value represents sea depth or a sea depth interval.

So with `dl` it could look like this:

```
<dl>
    <dt><time datetime="12h 39m"><time>09:21</time> to <time>22:00</time></time></dt>
    <dd>Run the dog!</dd>
    <dt><time datetime="5m"><time>22:00</time> to <time>22:05</time></time></dt>
    <dd>Have a beer!</dd>
</dl>
```

(This would also allow you to skip times, e.g., in case you didn’t really run the dog from 09:21 to 22:00.)

A semantically weaker variant (e.g., if you don’t want to provide the end time in the same element) would be something like this:

```
    <dt><time datetime="5m"><time>22:00</time></time></dt>
```

In that case, you would have to provide an empty `dd` element for the last time (or whatever makes sense in your case).

Comment: A reasonable approach, thanks. I meanwhile came to a similar conclusion, in that I agree the best compromise is to include both start and end time for every list item. Then, whenever the end time of an item happens to coincide with a start time of the next item, there is the option to use a bit of CSS and Javascript to hide one of the two -- for the sake of cosmetic appeal. (Also, thank you for upvoting my question from the -1 score it was at for reasons I cannot begin to comprehend.)